# How to join the data of 'Mech' into 'Tech' data?

Tags: c#

I am trying to join the data of "MECHANICAL" to "TECHNICAL" but I don't know how to do it.

This is my current code that list all the Data under DecodedFactoryOptions:
At first, I groupby every equipments by their Categories..

```
 public static IEnumerable<VehicleFactoryOptionModel> GetFactoryOptions(IEnumerable<DecodedFactoryOption> options)
        {
            var optionEquipment = new List<VehicleFactoryOptionModel>();

            if (options == null) return optionEquipment;

            var optEquip = options.GroupBy(e => e.Category);

            foreach (var equip in optEquip)
            {
                var optionalEquipment = new VehicleFactoryOptionModel { Data = new List<VehicleCategoryOptionModel>()};

                if (equip != null)
                {
                    foreach (var eq in equip)
                    {
                        optionalEquipment.TypeId = eq.OptionHeaderId;
                        optionalEquipment.Description = eq.Description;
                        optionalEquipment.Data.Select(d => d.StyleIds == eq.AppliedStyleId);
                        optionalEquipment.chromeCode = eq.chromeCode;
                        optionalEquipment.oemCode = eq.oemCode;
                        optionalEquipment.optionKindId = eq.optionKindId;
                        if (eq.OptionCategoryId == null) continue;
                        FillOptionCategoryInfo(eq, optionalEquipment);
                    }
                }

                optionEquipment.Add(optionalEquipment);
            }

            return optionEquipment;
        }
```

The result of the above code is :

```
[
    {
        "TypeId": 1236,
        "TypeName": "MECHANICAL",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Description": "Engine: 5.7L V8 DOHC 32V FFV w/i-Force",
                "Categories": [
                    {
                        "Id": 1052,
                        "Name": "Engine-8 Cyl"
                    }
                ],
                "StyleIds": [
                    362074,
                    362107
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description": "Engine: 5.7L V8 DOHC 32V FFV w/i-Force",
                "Categories": [
                    {
                        "Id": 1213,
                        "Name": "Fuel System-Flex Fuel"
                    }
                ],
                "StyleIds": [
                    362074,
                    362107
                ]
            }
    },
    {
        "TypeId": 1176,
        "TypeName": "TECHNICAL",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Description": "Tires: P275/55R20 Bridgestone/Dunlop Performance",
                "Categories": [
                    {
                        "Id": 1092,
                        "Name": "Tire-Front-Performance"
                    }
                ],
                "StyleIds": [
                    362074,
                    362107
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description": "Tires: P275/55R20 Bridgestone/Dunlop Performance",
                "Categories": [
                    {
                        "Id": 1097,
                        "Name": "Tire-Rear-Performance"
                    }
                ],
                "StyleIds": [
                    362074,
                    362107
                ]
            },
    {
        "TypeId": 10689,
        "TypeName": "ENTERTAINMENT",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Description": "Radio: Entune Premium w/JBL Audio & Navigation -inc: AM/FM/HD radio, CD player MP3/WMA playback capability, high-resolution 7\" touch-screen display, auxiliary audio jack, USB 2.0 port, iPod connectivity and control, iTunes Tagging, traffic and weather, JBL speakers and amplifier, Bluetooth hands-free phone capability, phone book access, voice recognition and music streaming, Entune App Suite includes Bing, iHeartRadio, MovieTickets.com, OpenTable, Pandora, Yelp and Facebook Places; real-time info including traffic, weather, fuel prices, sports and stocks, SIRIUSXM Satellite Radio, 90-day free trial",
                "Categories": [
                    {
                        "Id": 1014,
                        "Name": "Audio-AM/FM Stereo"
                    }
                ],
                "StyleIds": [
                    362074,
                    362107
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description": "Radio: Entune Premium w/JBL Audio & Navigation -inc: AM/FM/HD radio, CD player MP3/WMA playback capability, high-resolution 7\" touch-screen display, auxiliary audio jack, USB 2.0 port, iPod connectivity and control, iTunes Tagging, traffic and weather, JBL speakers and amplifier, Bluetooth hands-free phone capability, phone book access, voice recognition and music streaming, Entune App Suite includes Bing, iHeartRadio, MovieTickets.com, OpenTable, Pandora, Yelp and Facebook Places; real-time info including traffic, weather, fuel prices, sports and stocks, SIRIUSXM Satellite Radio, 90-day free trial",
                "Categories": [
                    {
                        "Id": 1017,
                        "Name": "Audio-CD Player"
                    }
                ],
                "StyleIds": [
                    362074,
                    362107
                ]
            },
```

I wanted the "MECHANICAL"'s data will be join into the "TECHNICAL" data.

Here is my desired result:

```
{
        "TypeId": 1176,
        "TypeName": "TECHNICAL",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Description": "Tires: P275/55R20 Bridgestone/Dunlop Performance",
                "Categories": [
                    {
                        "Id": 1092,
                        "Name": "Tire-Front-Performance"
                    }
                ],
                "StyleIds": [
                    362074,
                    362107
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description": "Tires: P275/55R20 Bridgestone/Dunlop Performance",
                "Categories": [
                    {
                        "Id": 1097,
                        "Name": "Tire-Rear-Performance"
                    }
                ],
                "StyleIds": [
                    362074,
                    362107
                ]
            },

                "Description": "Engine: 5.7L V8 DOHC 32V FFV w/i-Force",
                "Categories": [
                    {
                        "Id": 1052,
                        "Name": "Engine-8 Cyl"
                    }
                ],
                "StyleIds": [
                    362074,
                    362107
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description": "Engine: 5.7L V8 DOHC 32V FFV w/i-Force",
                "Categories": [
                    {
                        "Id": 1213,
                        "Name": "Fuel System-Flex Fuel"
                    }
                ],
                "StyleIds": [
                    362074,
                    362107
                ]
            }
    {
```

Comment: are you only interested in data array where typename is mechanical or technical? That is, you are not interested in type id? You have currently chose the type id randomly. Have you tried to filter on typename using linq?

Comment: @peeyushsingh yes.. I wanted the typeName and Id of the MECHANICAL will not be included in the result, but the DATA of it will be join/transfered to the TECHNICAL..

Comment: Seems like your style ids are same for Mechanical and Technical to match? Did you try using them to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following would work, do keep in mind that I did not test

```
  // instead of new add the call to get the Ienumerable
  IEnumerable<VehicleFactoryOptionModel> optionModels = new List<VehicleFactoryOptionModel>();
  // fill type name and id for the technical
  var result = optionModels.Select(x => new {x.TypeId, x.TypeName, x.Data}).
      Where(x => x.TypeName.ToString() == "Technical").ToList();

  // select only the data list for mechanical
  var test = optionModels.
      Where(x=>x.TypeName.ToString() == "Mechanical").SelectMany(x=>x.Data );

  // add it to the technical list,
  // assumption that there will be only one list for the techincal..thats why the index 0
  result[0].Data.AddRange(test);
```

Comment: the result will be NULL since, the optionModels doesnt have value yet.. The data was came from DecodedOptions,

Comment: I know, that line needs to be replaced by your call...since I do not have the class structure.